# how can I show a hidden text to frame 2 when div in frame 1 is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm having trouble with iframes. what i want to happen is that, everytime i will click a div layer from the frame1 i want the content of that(the hidden text from frame1) to be displayed inside the frame2, but i can't. i don't know. any help is appreciated. thank you in advance. i jjust got this code from the internet and applied it to mine.

this is the sample code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
    }
```

html code:

```
<div class = "list-container"  onclick="setVisibility('dev-01', 'inline');";>hello</div><div id  = "dev-01" style = "display:none;" target = "frame2">hello people</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access from `html` to `js` you need add listener to first div from js script

like:

```
<body>
  <div id="first" class = "list-container">hello</div>
  <div id  = "dev-01" style = "display:none;" target = "frame2">
  hello people</div>
  <script>
     (function () {
       'use strict';
       var el = document.getElementById("first")
       el && el.addEventListener("click", clickFirst);

       function clickFirst () {
          setVisibility('dev-01', 'inline');
       }
       function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
         document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
       }

      })();  
   </script>
 </body>
```